# Loading ng-include partials from local pre-loaded (JST) template cache

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include, jst, angular-template

I have my template pre-loaded in a javascript string array, like `var t = JST['firstTemplate']`, where `t` would be like,

```
<div>This scope has a value of {{value}}</div>
```

How can I use this pre-loaded template in an `ng-include` directive?

Note that my template in this scenario can be more complex, with possible nested view and templates and their own nested scopes and controllers. So I am not sure if any of the ng-bind directives would help?

UPDATE:

Looking at the source of `ng-include` it appears that a good way to do this would be to decouple the template loading logic into a customizable provider.

The current default loading mechanism simply does a `$http.get` with `$templateCache` as the cache provider. It seems like I can inject my template content in `JST['firstTemplate']` into the template cache, but I'd have to do that at startup time, for every template.

```
$templateCache.put('firstTemplate', JST['firstTemplate']);
```

and then have,

```
<div ng-include="firstTemplate"></div>
```

I could also write a custom directive that goes side-by side with every ng-include, that somehow does this pre-caching of templates. That again seem clunky.

UPDATE #2

I'm going to try overriding the templateCache, so that it uses my already pre-loaded JST hash. Will post the results if this works.

Comment: Just for the protocol: `<div ng-include="'firstTemplate'"></div>` If you do not pass a string to ng-include, it tries to get the value from a scope variable with this name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to work, and it's not a hack like I was thinking earlier (above :-) Basically, decorate the $templateCache.get method using standard $provide.decorator so that cache gets look in my local pre-loaded cache. It just works.

```
angular.module('app').config([
  '$provide', 
  function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$templateCache', function($delegate, $sniffer) {
      var originalGet = $delegate.get;

      $delegate.get = function(key) {
        var value;
        value = originalGet(key);
        if (!value) {
          // JST is where my partials and other templates are stored
          // If not already found in the cache, look there...
          value = JST[key]();
          if (value) {
            $delegate.put(key, value);
          }
        }
        return value;
      };

      return $delegate;
    });

    return this;
  }
]);
```

If you're wondering why I have this stuff in JST, we use a rails backend and the rails asset pipeline to deliver all angular assets. The JST templates allow us to bundle all templates and load them into the app during initialization, and avoid additional server roundtrips that are normally required when fetching partials and other template content.

The above patch makes all of this works with angular.

Comment: Thank you for this patch also. I was using the raw JST Source. Now to play with this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-include`, use `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div ng-bind-html="t"></div>
```

On your controller, place the template on the `$scope`:

```
$scope.t = JST['firstTemplate'];
```

You will need to include `ngSanitize` as a submodule (don't forget to add `angular-sanitize.js` too):

```
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Comment: From the documents, it looks like ng-bind-html does _not_ compile the template nor do other things ng-include does, like creating a new scope for it. I think want all that to happen. Am I mistaken on how ng-bind-html works?

Comment: You can use the `$compile` service for that.

Comment: Almost seems like we need an option on ng-include to tell it to use the template cache.

Answer (score 0):

today i am faced with the same problem, here is my solution:

A custom directive, which return the JST"server/info" as template:

```
/* jstTemplate.js */

/**
 * @desc template loader for JST templates
 * @example <div jst-template="server/info.html"></div>
 */


angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('jstTemplate', jstTemplate);

function jstTemplate() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: function(element, attrs) {
            return JST[attrs.jstTemplate]();
        }
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
<div class="box">
    <div jst-template="server/info.html"></div>
</div>
```

The `attrs.jstTemplate` contains the value, we provided in the directive.

Cheers,
Niklas