# What is JST in angular template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, linemanjs

Recently I came across a code chunck where JST is added before the template in angular -

Example -

`$routeProvider
  .when("/login", {
    template: JST["app/templates/login"],
    controller: "LoginController"
  })`

Previously, I do like this -

`$routeProvider
  .when("/login", {
    template: "app/templates/login",
    controller: "LoginController"
  })`

what is this `JST` in angular template means? also the difference between the two styles if any?

FYI - Its a code in app made from `linemanjs`.

Comment: I don't think it's an angular feature. Isn't `JST` declared somewhere? Or is your script maybe preprocessed, and it's some kind of macro?

Comment: If it's a SailsJS app, then it'll support JST (see my answer below)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It possibly could be an hash object in your code containing all keys and values as template urls for html files.

```
var JST = {
    "app/templates/login":"something.html"
};

$routeProvider
    .when("/login", {
        template: JST["app/templates/login"],
        controller: "LoginController"
    })
```

Comment: I made a folder search with `JST` but no results, I think I am using `linemanjs` (installed globally `-g`) so it must be there if not available locally and not explicitly an angular feature

Comment: Yes, it must be somewhere else. Its definitely not an angular feature

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I use JST templates in Angular:

```
app.factory('$jst', ['$sce', function($sce) {
  var methods = {
    template: function(name) { return $sce.trustAsHtml( eval(JST[name])() ) }
  };
  return methods;
}]);

app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$jst', function($scope, $http, $jst) {
  $scope.template = $jst.template('name-of-my-template');
}]);
```

...and here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="SomeCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="template"></div>
</div>
```

It's a simple and elegant way to use JST templates from inside AngularJS.

PS It works well with SailsJS too.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is using JST templates, [this page describes them](http://ricostacruz.com/backbone-patterns/#jst_templates).  JST is a hash that returns the template as a JavaScript function.  Often this JST object (hash of functions) is created at build time and saved as a JavaScript file that is included somehow by the app.  The input to the compiled JST object is a list of template .html files.

Comment: Yes. See https://code.google.com/p/trimpath/wiki/JavaScriptTemplates and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080981/loading-ng-include-partials-from-local-pre-loaded-jst-template-cache for more info on this.